# Any way to kill a crashed app on a non-rooted CM11s device?

Tags: cyanogenmod, crashes, oneplus-one

Every once in a while, I find my phone battery draining unusually quickly, and the 3rd-party "OS Monitor" tool shows some app running in the background, using lots of CPU when it's not supposed to. Sometimes, it's a music app actually playing audible music in the background, despite no evidence that the app is running - no notifications, and nothing in the recent apps list. Invariably, if I open the app info screen and click "Force Stop," it does nothing at all.

Certainly an enthusiast-friendly, developer-friendly system like CM has *some* way to kill a frozen app... right? Without rooting my phone, is there anything I can do other than rebooting when this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

Settings > Apps > Running

Once here, you can manually kill the app's processes. Also, there is a button at the top called "Show Cached Processes". You can also remove the cached processes from there.

Note: Removing the cached processes will kill the (cached) process of course, but the next time you launch the app, it will again call the necessary initialization functions to work, using more clock cycles. It is preferred not to kill the cached processes. But if you there is an app that's behaving weird, then go ahead and kill it!

**Original Comment**

open the app and hold press the back button... it should kill the app... also, why not disable the app that's draining your battery?

Comment: Interesting, I didn't realize that choosing a running app under "Settings > Apps > Running" gives different options then choosing the same app under Settings > Apps > Downloaded" or opening "App info" from the launcher or the notifications list. Stranger still that the "Force stop" button on the latter screen doesn't actually force anything, while the "Stop" button on the "Running" app info screen is more aggressive. Not the most intuitive design :)